# PHP RSS based schedule

Tags: php, rss

I have a (probably) simple PHP question. I'm pulling a schedule from an RSS feed. The RSS output looks like such:

```
17th Jan 2011 : Day 2
18th Jan 2011 : Day 3
19th Jan 2011 : Day 4
20th Jan 2011 : Day 5
```

I'm trying to remove all the information so only "Day x" remains. The schedule runs on an 8 day cycle, however I am limiting the RSS parser to only one Day so I get the current day.

I'm using this to pull the RSS:

```
$rss->parse();
$rss->showStories('1');
```

After a bit of tinkering I came up with this.

```
$i=1;
while($i<=8) {
    if (preg_match("/Day 3/i", "Day ".$i)) {
        echo $i;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Obviously the problem starts here:

```
if (preg_match("/Day 3/i", "Day ".$i)) {
```

I want this to find what the current schedule day is and then display corresponding data. Am I approaching this the right way could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

EDIT: Fixed code is below for anyone that wants it:

```
<?php
$url = "";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss) {
    $items = $rss->channel->item;
        foreach($items as $item) {
            foreach ($item->title as $story) {
                if (!preg_match(date("/jS M Y/"), $story)) continue;
                preg_match("/Day (\d+)/", $story, $m);
                echo $m[1]; // should print "2" if today is January 17
                break; // stop searching
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you're asking. What exactly is the thing you'd like to get in the end?

Comment: Basically, I want a daily schedule based of what "day" it is - so when the RSS feed says it's Day 2 I can have it display information pertaining to Day 2. I hope I'm making this clear enough ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which RSS library you are using, but something along the lines of

```
foreach ($rss->stories as $story) {
    // skips stories that are not today
    if (!preg_match(date("/jS M Y/"), $story)) continue;

    preg_match("/Day (\d+)/", $story, $m);
    echo $m[1]; // should print "2" if today is January 17

    break; // stop searching
}
```

could work. But without any more code it is hard to help further.

Comment: I wasn't referring to because I didn't know the best way to approach that - I'll try this out now thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway to just cut everything out so I have "Day X"?

Comment: You need to show a little more code so that I can give a more specific answer.

Comment: $rssData = $rss->showStories('1');

echo str_replace(date("jS M Y"), "test" ,$rssData);

$rssData would output as 17th Jan 2011 : Day 2

Comment: I looked at the above code and I seem to be getting an error on this line:     if (!preg_match(date("/jS M Y/")), $story)) continue;

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still getting an error. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() here   foreach ($rss->showStories('2') as $story) {

Comment: check what showStories returns (e.g. with var_dump($rss->showStories('2'));. I actually believe that you should try to replace this with something like i wrote above (foreach ($rss->stories as $story) {)

Comment: Odd...vardump is returning this:
17th Jan 2011 : Day 2
18th Jan 2011 : Day 3
NULL

Comment: Well, I just made a "fake" array and populated it with dates and it's working so I'm getting somewhere!